# What is the role of "py_binary"?

Tags: bazel

py_binary finally generates an executable file or an alias for a py script? What are its benefits? If it is an executable file, it will lose the meaning of python.

Answer (score 1):

Making something executable can be just adding a `chmod +x` and slapping a `#!/foo/bar` line on top, the thing itself is still whatever interpreter code it was before.

In the case of bazel, it will add a wrapper script that will set up an execution environment before dispatching to the Python code. Consider e.g. Bazel's runfiles, but also other `py_library` targets.

In addition, you can use the target in places where an executable is required as attribute for another target. A single Python file doesn't have any dependencies Bazel knows about, so that would technically fit there but would not integrate well with Bazel.